# Firewalld port forward reports Connection refused

Tags: networking, firewalld

I want to forward `9876` of `192.168.9.111` to `192.168.9.112:3333`, configured as follows:

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports: 9876/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: port=9876:proto=tcp:toport=3333:toaddr=192.168.9.112
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 

# sysctl -a |grep forward |grep 4
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.default.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.docker0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.docker0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.conf.lo.forwarding = 1
net.ipv4.conf.lo.mc_forwarding = 0
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward_use_pmtu = 0

# the destination is listening:
# telnet 192.168.9.112 3333
Trying 192.168.9.112...
Connected to 192.168.9.112.
Escape character is '^]'.

# but the forward does not work
# telnet 192.168.9.111 9876
Trying 192.168.9.111...
telnet: connect to address 192.168.9.111: Connection refused
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out your also need to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` to include:

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Answer (score 1):

net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 already set 1
and he is not trying to ping, he is connecting via telnet